# Reordering Gradle default tasks

Tags: android, gradle

I'm tryin' to migrate Android project from Ant to Gradle. There are native code and all calls of Java code from JNI in project are obfuscated by custom ant target. So in Ant targets calling in order:

- compile java code
- run proguard
- custom task that modifying JNI code according to mapping.txt after proguard
- native build

In Gradle I use JNI build method, described there https://gist.github.com/pboos/5802233#file-ndk-build-gradle.
In Gradle calling order seems to be:

- build native
- compile java code
- run proguard
- custom task for modifying

What should I do, so that native build will run AFTER proguard?

In other words, I need to define task, which will be executed after proguard, if it exists.

Comment: AFAIK, You will always need to `NOT obfuscate` java-native methods, The sample proguard config that comes along with the SDK `keeps` all java native methods

Comment: I know it, but in the project there is CUSTOM ant task that obfuscates  java-native methods and i can't just throw it away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I'm interpreting your question right, but it sounds like you are just looking for dependencies.

If `buildNative` can **only** run after `customModifications` then use a standard dependency:

```
buildNative {
    dependsOn customModifications
}
```

If `buildNative` must run after `customModifications`, but **only** if `customModifications` is requested use `mustRunAfter`:

```
buildNative {
   mustRunAfter customModifications
}
```